# The only limit that gets to $1$?

Tags: calculus, limits

$$\lim_{x\to 0} \frac{\sin(\pi x)}{e^{ax}-1}=1$$
has only one real solution, when $a=\pi$

I find this absolutely fascinating. Is there a proof or explanation of this phenomenon?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is a consequence of

- $\displaystyle \lim_{x\to 0} \dfrac{\sin(k x)}{x}=k$
- $\displaystyle \lim_{x\to 0} \dfrac{e^{ax}-1}{x}=a$

which should be fairly obvious from the early terms of the series expansions

- $\sin(k x) = kx -\dfrac{(kx)^3}{3!}+\cdots$
- $e^{ax} = 1 + ax +\dfrac{(ax)^2}{2!}+\dfrac{(ax)^3}{3!}+\cdots$

Answer (score 4):

**Hint**. By L'Hospital rule, you just have
$$
\lim_{x\to 0} \frac{\sin(\pi x)}{e^{ax}-1}=\lim_{x\to 0} \frac{\pi\cos(\pi x)}{a\:e^{ax}}=\frac{\pi}a.
$$

Comment: That's not a hint, it's a solution.

Comment: It has to be completed by proving that $a=\pi$ is the only value :)

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** $$\lim_{x\to0}\dfrac{\sin(\pi x)}{e^{ax}-1}=\lim_{x\to0}\dfrac{\sin(\pi x)}{x}\dfrac{x-0}{e^{ax}-e^{a\cdot 0}}=\lim_{x\to0}\pi\dfrac{\sin(\pi x)}{\pi x}\left(\dfrac{e^{ax}-e^{a\cdot 0}}{x-0}\right)^{-1},$$
$\displaystyle\lim_{x\to0}\dfrac{\sin(\pi x)}{\pi x}=1$, and $\displaystyle\lim_{x\to0}\dfrac{e^{ax}-e^{a\cdot 0}}{x-0}=\left.\dfrac{\rm d}{{\rm d}x}e^{ax}\right|_{x=0}=ae^{a\cdot 0}=a$.

Answer (score 1):

for a isnot 0,sin($\pi x$)~$\pi$x,$e^ax-1$~$ax$
hence the limit is $\frac{\pi}{a}$

(because sinx=x+o(x),$e^x$=1+x+o(x))

Answer (score 1):

HINT: $$\dfrac{\sin\pi x}{e^{ax}-1}=\dfrac\pi a\cdot\dfrac{\sin\pi x}{\pi x}\cdot\dfrac1{\dfrac{e^{ax}-1}{ax}}$$

Can you take it from here?